# HTTPS requests failing after SSL certificate change in server

Tags: java, ssl, https, pki, ca

I have two java applications. Java application "L" calls REST API hosted by java application "D". It was working fine until "D"s certificate expired. I changed the CA from digicert to Telia. Now I could see from "L"s logs that API calls are failing without any proper error message. I couldn't see any error messages from the "D"'s  logs as well. I suspected failure at the SSL level. So I tried using curl to call the API from "L"'s machine. Curl command is able to call the API successfully. So I took TCP dump of the traffic between "L" and "D" and I could see this:

```
3 5    0.0032   (0.0000)    S>C    Handshake
        ServerHelloDone
3 6    0.0042   (0.0010)    C>S    Alert
      level               fatal
      value               certificate_unknown
```

I think "certificate_unknown" means the "L" is not able to get the root CA file in the new Telia cert chain. Is my understanding correct? but why is curl command working then? Does java not have access to the system root CAs?

Comment: _Oracle_ Java by default uses a file supplied as part of the Java package, normally JRE/lib/security/cacerts but can be overridden by =/jssecacerts, (both) completely separate from any OS-defined CA-store. _OpenJDK_ Java depends on the builder or packager and environment; it may default to its own store or an OS store or something else. In both cases a Java application can easily override the Java default and use something else, and without details about the application it is impossible to even guess what it is doing.

Comment: FWIW, Oracle cacerts has included [Telia Sonera Root CA v1](https://crt.sh/?q=DD%3A69%3A36%3AFE%3A21%3AF8%3AF0%3A77%3AC1%3A23%3AA1%3AA5%3A21%3AC1%3A22%3A24%3AF7%3A22%3A55%3AB7%3A3E%3A03%3AA7%3A26%3A06%3A93%3AE8%3AA2%3A4B%3A0F%3AA3%3A89) since 8u171, 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the truststore of L. It must either contain D's current certificate, or any of the signing authorities' certificate - otherwise L will not trust that it is communicating to the intended D and stop communicating.

There should be an exception thrown on L side about this, but it depends what L sends to the log or stdout before you can see it.

Comment: I was  able to resolve the issue by adding the Telia CA cert to java truststore:

`keytool -import -alias teliasonerarootcav1 -keystore /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.ca`